# When an image on an editing program is rendered on Windows, is the program parsing it, or is the kernel doing it?

Tags: drivers, images, kernel, parsing

so I know this question is confusing, but luckily I am a computer programmer and can make it more clear if you would help me out by reading on.

A simple program, liek MS-Paint, will "know" how to render an image by its format, magic number, and programmed software capabilities based across an array of functionable libraries, DLLs, and APIs.

On Windows, for example, the Windows API has a native rendering capability of BMP file format without any external header libraries needed, so you'd have to either download a library that can extrapolate the format and communicate with a library for the OS, or make your own.

But what I want to know is, when using painting program, does the kernel, when doing a system call for access of the video driver, know the image data parsed, or does the program do everything and all the kernel does is tell the driver what to do based on the library?

Hope it makes sense, and hope this is the right cateogy

Comment: This smells like a homework question to me.

Comment: Could be either way. Some programs, likely the ones built into windows, would use the native GDI+ calls to do rendering. Others may use their own libraries. There is no mandate to use the built-in win32 functions for image handling, but it can be easier.